# Is there a way to set a default cooldown for commands in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So I need all of my commands to have a two second cooldown, is there a way to set a default cooldown for all of them (as opposed to individually adding it using decorators)? If so, are you also able to change other specific commands to separate cooldowns in addition? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after looking at the discord module I found a really simple solution to give each command a cooldown, it can very easily be modified to give different cooldowns for different commands and just automate cooldowns instead of using the decorator

```py
default_cooldown = commands.Cooldown(1, 2, commands.BucketType.user)
for command in self.bot.commands:
    command._buckets._cooldown = default_cooldown
```

Answer (score 0):

discord.py has a [decorator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown) for cooldowns.

```py
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType

@commands.cooldown(rate,per,BucketType)
```

*A cooldown allows a command to only be used a specific amount of times in a specific time frame. These cooldowns can be based either on a per-guild, per-channel, per-user, per-role or global basis. Denoted by the third argument of type which must be of enum type BucketType.

If a cooldown is triggered, then CommandOnCooldown is triggered in on_command_error() and the local error handler.

A command can only have a single cooldown.*

Comment: Oh yes, I understand the decorators, but is there a way to set all the commands to a certain cooldown, without adding the decorator to every single command?

Comment: @Judev1 Using the decorator is the only way other than modifying the internals of discord.py

Comment: Actually after revisiting some of my code, I took a deeper look and found a solution